# Solr custom query component does not return correct facet counts

Tags: plugins, solr

I have a simple Solr query component as follows:

```
public class QueryPreprocessingComponent extends QueryComponent implements PluginInfoInitialized {
    
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( QueryPreprocessingComponent.class );

  private ExactMatchQueryProcessor exactMatchQueryProcessor;

  public void init( PluginInfo info ) {
    initializeProcessors(info);
  }

  private void initializeProcessors(PluginInfo info) {
    List<PluginInfo> queryPreProcessors = info.getChildren("queryPreProcessors")
            .get(0).getChildren("queryPreProcessor");
    for (PluginInfo queryProcessor : queryPreProcessors) {
      initializeProcessor(queryProcessor);
    }
  }

  private void initializeProcessor(PluginInfo queryProcessor) {
    QueryProcessorParam processorName = QueryProcessorParam.valueOf(queryProcessor.name);
    switch(processorName) {
      case ExactMatchQueryProcessor:
        exactMatchQueryProcessor = new ExactMatchQueryProcessor(queryProcessor.initArgs);
        LOG.info("ExactMatchQueryProcessor initialized...");
        break;
      default: throw new AssertionError();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void prepare( ResponseBuilder rb ) throws IOException
  {
    if (exactMatchQueryProcessor != null) {
      exactMatchQueryProcessor.modifyForExactMatch(rb);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void process(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException
  {
    // do nothing - needed so we don't execute the query here.
    return;
  }

}
```

This works as expected functionally except when I use this in a distributed request, it has an issue with facets counts returned. It doubles the facet counts.

Note that I am not doing anything related to faceting in plugin. `exactMatchQueryProcessor.modifyForExactMatch(rb);` does a very minimal processing if the query is quoted otherwise it does nothing. Even if the incoming query is not quoted, facet count issue is there. Even if I comment everything inside prepare function, issue persists.

Note that this component is declared in as first-components in solrconfig.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by extending the class to `SearchComponent` instead of `QueryComponent`. It seems that SearchComponent sits at higher level of abstraction than QueryComponent and is useful when you want to work on a layer above shards.